# regex for admitting blank spaces between words in a name in jquery validate

Tags: regex, jquery-validate

I'm using the following rule in jquery validate to make a name field, called nombre, only accept letters.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("nombre", function(value, element, param) {



   return jQuery.trim(value).match(new RegExp("^(?:" + param + ")$"));





});



$("#nombre").rules("add", { nombre: "[a-zA-Z]+"})
```

I want the regex to accept something like

```
Polly Jean Harvey
```

or

```
P.J. Harvey
```

as valid names, (they are currently rejected). How can I add space between words and periods to the regex? Of course, I still want to reject blank names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[a-zA-Z. ]+` as a regex.

It will accept spaces and dots.

But You can have different names such as "Pierre-Henry de la Brancardière". And this sort of name would be invalid.

As javascript doesn't support unicode with `\p` I would suggest you to do a blacklist of invalid characters instead of a whitelist.